ASP classic cant change data in Application by ajax request
I try to call a simple ajax request from client side to server side, but I have a problem with it
when I press the button I have no change in this page even when I got the alert("OK!"); and for example if my Application("bbb") is 51 I always got OK! and then 51
only when I have refresh the page I see all the changes in my button for example If is press the button 8 times and Application("bbb") is 51 I got 8 times of alerts
as OK! and then 51 and no change for <label id="lbl"></label> it still have 51 in text and when I refresh the page I got in <label id="lbl"></label> 0 in text
and after next click I got <label id="lbl"></label> change to 61
that mean the ajax request got the server and change the value in Application("bbb") as expected but I cant cahnge the html view without refreshing the page
why its happen?
this is my simple code :
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
 <button id="changeSessionBtn">Change Session Variable</button>
  <label id="lbl">0</label>
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#changeSessionBtn').click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://localhost/home.asp', 
                    data: { newSessionValue: 'newValue' },
                    success: function(response){
                       document.getElementById('lbl').innerHTML = <%=Application("bbb")%>
                       alert("OK!");
                       alert(<%=Application("bbb")%>);
                       //$("lbl").innerHTML = 
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error){
                        console.error('Error changing session variable:', error);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

    </body>
</html>


<%

if IsEmpty(Application("bbb")) then
    Application("bbb") = 1
Else
    Application("bbb") = Application("bbb") + 1
end if

%>


The problem is the server-side processing has already happened so the value of the innerHTML is already set before the AJAX result is returned. Instead write the value of Application("bbb") back as a response from the AJAX request.

Relevant: What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?. The server side code in that post happens to be php but it doesn't matter - the principles and the nature of the problem are fundamentally the same

To solve your problem just change the position of your ASP code to the begin of  document as follow:


<%

if IsEmpty(Application("bbb")) then
    Application("bbb") = 1
Else
    Application("bbb") = Application("bbb") + 1
end if

%>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
 <button id="changeSessionBtn">Change Session Variable</button>
  <label id="lbl">0</label>
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#changeSessionBtn').click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://localhost/home.asp', 
                    data: { newSessionValue: 'newValue' },
                    success: function(response){
                       document.getElementById('lbl').innerHTML = <%=Application("bbb")%>
                       alert("OK!");
                       alert(<%=Application("bbb")%>);
                       //$("lbl").innerHTML = 
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error){
                        console.error('Error changing session variable:', error);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

    </body>
</html>




While that will "technically" work it does not help them understand why.

This also doesn't help if the setting of the Application variable is being set in a completely different ASP script being called by the AJAX method.

Make sure the Application object has been initialised in the global.asa file.
https://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_globalasa.asp
Also lock the Application object before writing to it and then unlock it again.

Nope. They are called "pre-processing" tags for a reason, the server-side processing happens before the HTML is rendered so the value of the innerHTML has already been determined before the AJAX code runs. The Application variable is behaving as expected.
